# Next.js dynamic route parameter undefined

Tags: typescript, mongodb, next.js, routes

I'm making an e-commerce next.js app with Typescript and MongoDB.
This is my current file structure I will be referring to:

[image: Folder Structure of my next.js app screenshot]

My mainPage.tsx file renders all of my products in cards. Using products.map and Link, I am linking each product to its product page like this:

```js
          {products.map((product: ProductModel) => (
            <Link
              key={product._id.toString()}
              href={{
                pathname: "/product",
                query: {
                  id: `${product._id.toString()}`,
                },
              }}
            >
              <CategoryCard product={product} />
            </Link>
          ))}
```

Here in my product/page.tsx file I get the id from searchParams and I know up to this point it works correctly, the "console.log("This is the id: ", searchParams.id);" line correctly shows the id. But it's the fetching of the product here

```js
const { product } = await getProduct(searchParams.id);
```

where it breaks and displays "Error fetching product details of product id {searchParams.id}" on the page. Here is the file:

```js
const getProduct = async (id: string) => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:3000/api/singleproduct?id=${id}`,
      {
        cache: "no-cache",
      }
    );

    if (!res.ok) {
      throw new Error(`Failed to fetch product with id ${id}`);
    }

    return res.json();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error fetching product:", err);
    throw err;
  }
};

const ProductPage = async ({
  searchParams,
}: {
  searchParams: { id: string };
}) => {
  console.log("This is the id: ", searchParams.id);

  try {
    const { product } = await getProduct(searchParams.id);

    return <div>This is a {product.product_title}</div>;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching product:", error);
    return (
      <div>Error fetching product details of product id {searchParams.id}</div>
    );
  }
};

export default ProductPage;
```

Now this is the api/singleproduct/route.tsx file where the problem probably originates from. Here's the code:

```js
import Product from "../../models/Product";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from "next";

export async function GET(req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) {
  console.log("Query parameters:", req.query);
  const id = req.query.id as string;
  console.log("this is the id:", id);

  try {
    if (!id) {
      throw new Error("ID parameter is missing.");
    }

    console.log("This is the id:", id);
    const product = await Product.findById(id);

    if (!product) {
      return NextResponse.json({ error: "Product not found" }, { status: 404 });
    }

    console.log("Product from MongoDB:", product);
    return NextResponse.json({ product }, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Something broke:", error);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "GET request failed.", error });
  }
}
```

I get "Query parameters: undefined" in the console and the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')". How can I fix this? Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution involves changing `NextApiRequest` to `NextRequest`.

In your `api/singleProduct/route.tsx`, you could use this line of code:

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET(req: NextRequest, res: NextResponse) {
    ...
    // This will get the "id" search parameter (/api/singleProduct?id=12345)
    const productId = req.nextUrl.searchParams.get("id");
    ...
}
```

Comment: You fixed it! Thank you!!